How can I perform optional sorting in Supabase?
Comments and replies each have an id and parentId. The required sorting is as follows:
When parentId is null, it should be compared using id, sorting in ascending order.
When parentId is the same, it should be compared using createdAt, sorting in ascending order based on the older entries.
I know how to sort by createdAt at the end, but how can I enable comparisons based on id when parentId is null?
Given the following data:
[
  { "id": 1, "parentId": null, "createdAt": "2024-10-20" },
  { "id": 2, "parentId": null, "createdAt": "2024-10-20" },
  { "id": 3, "parentId": 2, "createdAt": "2024-10-24" },
  { "id": 4, "parentId": 1, "createdAt": "2024-10-25" },
  { "id": 5, "parentId": 1, "createdAt": "2024-10-26" }
]

I hope to achieve the following sorting:
[
  { "id": 1, "parentId": null, "createdAt": "2024-10-20" }, // Comment with null parentId
  { "id": 4, "parentId": 1, "createdAt": "2024-10-25" }, // Reply to id 1
  { "id": 5, "parentId": 1, "createdAt": "2024-10-26" }, // Reply to id 1
  { "id": 2, "parentId": null, "createdAt": "2024-10-20" }, // Next comment with null parentId
  { "id": 3, "parentId": 2, "createdAt": "2024-10-24" }  // Reply to id 2
]

Currently, my code looks like this:
const { data, error } = await client
  .from("comments")
  .select("*")
  .eq("postId", postId)
  .or(
    `status.eq.active,id.in.(${parentIds.length > 0 ? parentIds.join(",") : ""})`
  ) // Fetch only active comments and replies
  .order("parentId", { ascending: true }) // Sort by parentId in ascending order
  .order("id", { ascending: true }) // Sort by id in ascending order
  .order("createdAt", { ascending: true }); // Sort by createdAt for entries with the same parentId

